# Change li Background Colour In Javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I wonder if someone can please advise me how I can do the following?

I have the below JS which changes the background colour of an li based on id (I'm using the li as buttons). When the li is clicked the background turns white. Can someone please tell me what I should add to return all other li elements to their original colour?

Many thanks

```
 $(function () {
            $("li").click(function (e) {
                document.getElementById(e.target.id).style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this more easily with a class:

```js
$('li').on('click', function() {
  $('.whitebg').removeClass('whitebg');
  $(this).addClass('whitebg');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: deepskyblue;
}
li {
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
.whitebg {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I was about to say, including a snippet or fiddle would make this answer even better, but I see that you've already done so! Nice answer